# adDidDismissFullScreenContent() is never called on version 8

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am using **GADRewardedAd** and my requirement is when ads closed then it showing a view. On API version 8 update `adDidPresentFullScreenContent()` is called but the **adDidDismissFullScreenContent()** method are never called.

```
private var rewardedAdView: GADRewardedAd!
GADRewardedAd.load(withAdUnitID: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.ADMOB_KEY_AD_REWARDED) ?? "",
                            request: GADRequest(), completionHandler: { (ad, error) in
                              if let error = error {
                                print("Rewarded ad failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                return
                              }
                              self.rewardedAdView = ad
                              self.rewardedAdView.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                            }
```

```
private func showRewardedAds(){
        self.isAdEarnComplete = false
        if let ad = rewardedAdView {
              ad.present(fromRootViewController: self,
                       userDidEarnRewardHandler: {
                               showToast(viewContoler: self, message: "Your coupon is ready!")
                       }
              )
    }
```

```
extension HomeViewController: GADFullScreenContentDelegate{
    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Rewarded ads present")
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Rewarded ads dismiss")
    }
    
       
    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        printLog(tag: TAG, message:  "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: is it failing for test id or for specific admob id?

Comment: @AmodGokhale No it's happed for both after upgrading the API. Please notice on the previous version it was working fine.

Comment: Can you compare below answered code with yours? Its working for me with 8.3.0

Comment: The link here is regarding interstitial ads in AdMob 8.3.0 but maybe also true for you. Ensure you **don't** load a new ad before the other is displayed and dismissed:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/-1lJ9aAsh7E

Comment: `self.rewardedAdView = ad` and `self.rewardedAdView.fullScreenContentDelegate = self` - don't you setup them twice?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure GADInterstitialAd instance is member variable or property for strong reference and don't set the instance as nil before call adDidDismissFullScreenContent.
For example:

1. interstitial(GADInterstitialAd) is local variable in the GADInterstitialAdLoadCompletionHandler, the variable interstitial will be released after completion callback finished and functions of delegate will not be called.
2. interstitial(GADInterstitialAd) is property of  UIViewController , immediately set interstitial as nil after call "interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)", the functions of delegate will not be called(Same reason, the variable will be released before call callback). You can set this property as nil in the adDidDismissFullScreenContent.

Comment: underrated comment - number 2 did it for me

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old thread, but maybe this helps somebody - I was loading new AD as soon as user received the reward, so this actually cleared the old GADRewardedAd reference and therefore adDidDismissFullScreenContent wasn't called.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32893069)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: for me this answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks for the great hint! I was loading ads in viewDidAppear() and new ads were being loaded on dismissal of the current ads, which resulted in the variable storing the ads data being overwritten by the new ads and adDidDismissFullScreenContent() was not called.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnRwdClick: UIButton!
    var rewadAd: GADRewardedAd?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        GADRewardedAd.load(
            withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313", request: GADRequest()
        ) { (ad, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Rewarded ad failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("Loading Succeeded")
            self.rewadAd = ad
            self.rewadAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func rewadAdTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        if let ad = rewadAd {
            ad.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
                let reward = ad.adReward
                print("Reward received with currency \(reward.amount), amount \(reward.amount.doubleValue)")
                
                // TODO: Reward the user.
            }
        } else {
            //Failed
        }
    }
    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Rewarded ad presented.")
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Rewarded ad dismissed.")
    }
    
    func ad(
        _ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd,
        didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error
    ) {
        print("Rewarded ad failed to present with error: \(error.localizedDescription).")
        
    }
    
}
```