# How can I implement AdMob Rewarded with using Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I want to add Rewarded AdMob in my iOS project which ı use swift not objective c.In Admob rewarded documents ı can't find information about how to add with using swift.(Link is [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded) )

Comment: check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67216783/2323607

Comment: Yes your answer will help to me.Thanks.
I want to ask one more question. According to your answer how can I detect to 
1)User close ad not watching any seconds
2)user watch all ad 
3) user wait 4-5 seconds to then click close button it means not watch all video ad.

Comment: I don't think 1 & 3 possible with version 8 api ( but I might be wrong - kindly check this document https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration#objective-c_9 or ask separate question for the same )

Comment: 2) in above code - let reward = ad.adReward will only be called if user watched complete ad